# .m3u8 live video isn't streaming on exoplayer

Tags: java, android, firebase, exoplayer

I don't know whether exoplayer don't supports .m3u8 file or not but it is showing this error in logcat.

I am getting links from firebase which has .m3u8 like

https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/ssai/event/fi5oKDz-RnC4XnNBHtxvOQ/master.m3u8

My Logcat filtering error...

```
2020-08-04 11:40:34.606 6199-6477/com.wordpress.myselfnikunj.mytv E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:924)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:846)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here is my exoPlayer.java

```
package com.wordpress.myselfnikunj.mytv;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;

import static android.view.View.GONE;

public class ExoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Initialize variable
    PlayerView playerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView btFullScreen;
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exo_player);

        //Assign variable
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        btFullScreen = findViewById(R.id.bt_fullscreen);

        //Make activity full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //VideoUrl
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String link = intent.getStringExtra("link");
        Uri videoUrl = Uri.parse(link);

        //Initialize load control
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        //Initialize band width meter
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        //Initialize track selector
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        );
        //Initialize simple exo player
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                this,trackSelector,loadControl
        );
        //Initialize data source factory
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                "exoplayer_video"
        );
        //Initialize extractors factory
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        //Initialize media source
        MediaSource   mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUrl
        ,factory,extractorsFactory,null,null);

        //Set player
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
        //Keep screen on
        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        //Prepare media
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        //Play video when ready
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                //Check condition
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                    //When Buffering
                    //Show progress Bar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                    //When ready
                    //Hide progress bar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });

        btFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Check condition
                if (flag) {
                    //When flag is true
                    //Set enter full screen image
                    btFullScreen.setImageDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen));
                    //Set potrait orientation
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    //Set flag value as false
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    //When flag is false
                    //Set exit full screen image
                    btFullScreen.setImageDrawable(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit));
                    //Set potrait orientation
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    //Set flag value as true
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Stop video when ready
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        //Get playback state
        simpleExoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        //Play video when ready
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        //Get playback state
        simpleExoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
    }
}
***

My XML file
***
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ExoPlayerActivity">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controller"
        app:fastforward_increment="10000"
        app:hide_on_touch="true"
        app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_simple_player_view"
        app:resize_mode="fit"
        app:rewind_increment="10000"
        app:show_timeout="5000"
        app:use_controller="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

YOU CAN SKIP THIS SINCE THE VIDEO ISN'T LOADING...
DESIGN DON'T MATTER IN ISSUE HERE I THINK SO...

My custom controller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/exo_rew"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_rew"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/exo_play"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/exo_pause"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/exo_ffwd"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ffwd"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exo_position"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:text="/"
                android:textColor="#CBCDC8" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exo_duration"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#CBCDC8" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt_fullscreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            app:buffered_color="#95989F"
            app:played_color="#FF0000"
            app:unplayed_color="#45424E" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Pls help if anyone has the required knowledge. I am stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

We have to use Hls media source for live streaming of .m3u8 file.

```
package com.wordpress.myselfnikunj.mytv;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

import static android.view.View.GONE;

public class ExoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Initialize variable
    PlayerView playerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView btFullScreen;
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
    boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exo_player);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        //Assign variable
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        btFullScreen = findViewById(R.id.bt_fullscreen);

        //Make activity full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Initialize band width meter
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        //Initialize track selector
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
        //Initialize simple exo player
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

        //video Url
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String link = intent.getStringExtra("link");
        Uri videoUrl = Uri.parse(link);

        //Initialize data source factory
        DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,Util.getUserAgent(this,"ExoPlayer"));

        //Initialize hlsMediaSource
        HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory).
                createMediaSource(videoUrl);

        //Initialize ConcatenatingMediaSource source
        ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(hlsMediaSource);

        //Set player
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        //Keep screen on
        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        //Prepare media
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(concatenatedSource);

        //Play video when ready
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                //Check condition
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                    //When Buffering
                    //Show progress Bar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                    //When ready
                    //Hide progress bar
                    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });

        btFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Check condition
                if (flag) {
                    //When flag is true
                    //Set enter full screen image
                    btFullScreen.setImageDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen));
                    //Set potrait orientation
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    //Set flag value as false
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    //When flag is false
                    //Set exit full screen image
                    btFullScreen.setImageDrawable(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit));
                    //Set potrait orientation
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    //Set flag value as true
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Stop video when ready
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        //Get playback state
        simpleExoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        //Play video when ready
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        //Get playback state
        simpleExoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
    }
}
```